# Flutter Amplify: No user pool for registered for this account

Tags: flutter, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I configured Amplify auth in my Flutter project although when I try to create a user I got the result message 'No user pool for registered for this account'. I also configured it through Amplify CLI.

I have got installed the last versions of the following libs:

- amplify_api
- amplify_flutter
- amplify_auth_cognito

```
...
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late bool _isAmplifyConfigured;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _isAmplifyConfigured = false;
    configureAmplify();
  }

  Future<void> configureAmplify() async {
    try {
      final api = AmplifyAPI();
      final auth = AmplifyAuthCognito();
      await Amplify.addPlugins([auth, api]);
      setState(() {
        _isAmplifyConfigured = true;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error configuring Amplify: $e");
    }
  }


...

Future<Either<String, SignUpResult>> signUp(String email, String password) async {
    final Map<AuthUserAttributeKey, String> userAttributes = {
      AuthUserAttributeKey.email: email
    };

    try {
      final result = await Amplify.Auth.signUp(
        username: email,
        password: password,
        options: SignUpOptions(userAttributes: userAttributes),
      );
      return right(result);
    } on AuthException catch (e) {
      return left(e.message);
    }
  }
```